# Get path of image to fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to get path of selected image in grid view to file-upload.

For example I get selected value in cell to textbox by code below

```
 txtucname.Text = gridusers.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

How to achieve that with file-upload

When editing any Customer record, if user doesn’t select any Image, the previous image is removed.

```
if (imgup.HasFile)
{
    string imgName = imgup.FileName.ToString();
    imgup.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Images/Customer/") + imgName);
    string imgPath = "../Images/Customer/" + imgName;
    string msg = c.UpdateCustomer(txtcustid.Text, txtucname.Text, imgPath);
    msg = "<br>Image Uploaded Successfully";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);

}
else
{
    string msg2 = c.UpdateCustomer(txtcustid.Text, txtucname.Text,,null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string Img1, unq1;
string filepath = "~/YourFolder/";
img1 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(gridusers.SelectedRow.Cells[2].ImageName);
unq1 = filepath + img1;
```

Comment: thank you one more thing the code will be Fileup. =unq1 ; .hasfile or what

Comment: if (fileup.HasFile) but if u are sure there will be filename then driectly upload to folder like    fileup.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(unq1));